# Android studio hello world project not showing on layout editor(design xml)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

When i'm trying to run a basic hello world project, the text "hello world" appears on the emulator. however it does not show on the design page of the activity_main.xml
[xml layout view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqW0q.png)

P.S. I'm using an old version(3.4) of android studio to develop for pepper robot and using the emulator provided by pepper sdk.

xml is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="688dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.37" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Tried using the "infer constraints button" but it was the same. I tried dropping a button on to the screen and it keeps going to the top left. I tried grabbing it back to the middle of the screen but I cant even click it once its reached the top. The problem is that I'm not able to use the layout designer cause it is not consistent with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**Rendering problems:**

Hi There, Sometimes, the layout editor might have trouble rendering the layout due to various reasons. Try the following steps to resolve rendering problems:

1. Click on the "Refresh" button in the layout editor toolbar to force
   a refresh of the layout.
2. Restart Android Studio to reset the layout editor.
3. Disable Instant Run if enabled. Go to **File -> Settings -> Build,
   Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run**, and uncheck the "Enable
   Instant Run" option.

> Note: Internet connection must be needed!

Comment: Md. Kabir Hassan - Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since most or all seven of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.